# Kafka connect - Transformers - Blacklist a nested field

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to remove a nested field using SMT with Kafka connect ?

I know the following works perfectly :

```
"transforms": "ReplaceField",
"transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "FieldFoo"
```

But this does not work ( assuming the nested field is foo->bar) :

```
"transforms": "ReplaceField",
"transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "FieldFoo.NestedFieldBar",
```

My data is in avro format.

I don't want to modify the data itself ( like flattening everything) to be able to do that. Any way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All (or at least most) of the Kafka Connect Transforms only work on top-level fields via `.get` and `.put` calls to a `Struct` or `Map<String, ?>`

You can inspect the source here -

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ReplaceField.java#L150-L163

I would suggest searching/opening a JIRA (and KIP) because it's a long-outstanding issue, IMO

The issue, though, would be that `"FieldFoo.NestedFieldBar"` is a valid String in itself, so it's hard to differentiate that between the following objects without extra characters like back-ticks or KSQL-like approach of `FieldFoo->NestedFieldBar`

```
"FieldFoo.NestedFieldBar": "value"
```

and

```
"FieldFoo" : { 
  "NestedFieldBar": "value"
}
```

Comment: Can we flatten nested ArrayList?

Comment: ArrayList isn't a builtin Connect type, but no, arrays cannot be flattened.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "flatten" transformer first to include a "." (period) within the nested fields.
So in your case the below should work.

```
"transforms": "flatten,ReplaceField",
"transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
"transforms.flatten.delimiter": "."
"transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "FieldFoo.NestedFieldBar"
```

Comment: The above solution is not working when you have any Arraylist on your data. Do you know how to tackle the Arraylist flatten and black list the Arraylist?